# Google play - Pending Publication - Flutter Firebase Google login

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

I built and uploaded my first android app to Google Play store which is built on top of Flutter+Firebase which uses only google auth sign-in.

Uploaded on Tuesday 10-July 8:00AM IST under internal test track and subsequently I made an update two hours later on the same day.I was not aware that the app needs to be reviewed by Google for internal testing as well. Hence I updated the store listing description with almost finalised content today afternoon.

All through the process, the status on the google play dashboard reads " Pending publication - Processing update".

My queries as a newbie developer are:

- The app doesn't progress from login screen unless authentication is successful.Does this need to be mandatorily given somewhere so that the review team can review the app.I presume this needs to be entered under "Sign-in" credentials but am not able to find the username and password field name from the flutter app dev tools?
- Is this waiting time normal? Contacted the support team but they just asked me to wait while I could see the normal processing time is lesser than 24hrs in most cases. I only request a handful of user permissions like Internet,Camera,Gallery and Microphone access and not doing anything unlawful.

Can someone please guide.

Ref link for point-1: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16921

Many thanks.

Comment: Check distribution percentage on console

Comment: @GaneshPokale Hi Ganesh, can you please tell me where to see this option. Under Pricing and Distribution, it reads "App availablity - Your app is currently unavailable on the Play Store." and release dashboard reads "Your app should have at least one production release that started on or after March 15th 2017 in order for any data to be generated and displayed here."

Comment: @Raghu Were able to eventually get your app published? If yes how long did it take?

Comment: @lordvcs The very first time took me whole 3 days and further updates took only about 1-2 hrs.